# Showing Dynamic Text Based on a table value in a Time Map in ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, timeslider, dynamic-text

I'm using ArcMap 10.7, and wanted to know if it's possible to show a value from a table on a map that corresponds to a time in a dynamic way.

Let's say my map shows the spread of Covid by zip code. As time progresses the map displays additional zip codes where covid cases appear. In the table of my shapefile, each row has the zip code, the date stamp and the total number of cases for that date.

[image]

I know in the time options you can display the time stamp on the map, but could I also display the Total cases for that particular time anywhere? Like as part of the legend?

I tried looking up information about using dynamic text, but I couldn't see anything for displaying a value from a table.

Answer (score 0):

You can **[enable time on your layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/map/time/enabling-time-on-your-data.htm)**. In the layer properties, click on the Time tab.

I would also read about [**visualizing temporal data**](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/map/time/about-visualizing-temporal-data.htm).In particular, have a look at **[adding time text to the display](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/map/time/adding-time-text-to-the-display.htm)**.

Comment: Thanks for the response Fezter. I've already got up to the point you've described, what I want to do is display the total number of cases along with the time. So in addition to showing the time text I want to show the total number of cases.